# As I have mentioned just before

Tags: grammar

Let's have this situation: Somebody is delivering a speech. In some period of time he is speaking about a particular topic. Then the speech is going on. After just a few minutes he/she is coming back to the topic by saying: *As I (have) mentioned just before…* Which tense is appropriate to use in such a situation: present perfect or just past simple?

Comment: Either one. But if it's BrE probably the present perfect. *As I (have) just mentioned* is a natural word order.

Answer (score 1):

There are many better ways to tell that. I'd say...

> As I mentioned ***earlier...***

I think the sentence without an *auxiliary* verb is fine (especially in speeches).

Comment: or "previously"

Comment: You can also get rid of the pronoun if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

> 1. Reiterating my point, ...
> 2. As previously mentioned, ...
> 3. If you remember from earlier, ...
> 4. As brought up before, ...

Comment: This answer "looks OK" to me, but it would be really nice of you to provide reasons and/or proofs of why these phrases are appropriate/applicable.